# Django testing form issue

Tags: python, django, forms, testing, view

i'm trying to write some test for my auction software written using django framework.
I'm having some problem, i've a form the asks to insert a comment, and it get also the auction id and the user id but these two parameters are not inserted by the user.
I know how to pass comment text, but how can i pass the auction and the user as a context??

I pass the comment in this way:

```
c = Client()
response = c.post('comment/', {'comment': 'example of comment'})
```

Comment: When the user clicks 'submit' in your form, does it post comment, user_id and auction_id? If it does just add those paramters to your post data in your test:

`response = c.post('comment/', {'comment': 'example of comment', 'user_id': 1, 'auction_id' 12})`

Comment: No, che only posts the comment

Comment: So presumably the view gets the user from request.user? In which case you need to log the user in with the test client. What about the auction, where does the view get that from?

Comment: Normally the view gets the auction with a query in the database, the view get the user with request.user.

Comment: If that is the case then what you're posting already should just work shouldn't it?

Log a user in with the test client, post the comment, the view gets the user from request.user, and makes a query for the auction - it works?

Comment: Solved! I used reverse('name_of_the_view') and now it works.